# how to extract hidden zip file from inside an image

Tags: image, cmd, winzip

Today I saw a way to concatenate a zip file along with an image. But is there anyway to separate the two files again?

To concatenate the files I types the following in command prompt:

```
copy /b imagefilename + zipfilename [filename with extensions]
```

Now how to I separate these files to access them individually?

Comment: one way might be to note the length of each file beforehand, so you know which offset to cut at.   Or look for the zip header --- https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pkzipfix` on the concatenated binary and it should write out the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you won't get much help here on this topic i already try.. What you can do either right click on the picture and goto unzip or open up winzip and open that pix that have the zip file hidden in and click unzip it should work. There isn't a way i have found yet to extract text from image on Command Prompt(cmd). What you can do with that is just open it up in text file or hex editor either one and your text or hidden message should be at the bottom of text file. Here how you can do this in cmd: C:>copy /b pixfilename.jpg pixfilename.txt    I hope this is any help.